# Optimising use of st_within for parallelisation

Tags: r, point-in-polygon, sf, parallel-processing

I'm trying to use st_within() to calculate points within polygons on a fairly complex shapefile. This operation tends to take 4-5 hours which is a bummer for debugging the code. I have access to a supercomputing cluster (120+ cores) and it seems sensible to make use of this tool to address this issue. However, it's unclear to me how I would even go about optimising these geospatial operations (from sf()) for multicore computing.

To get a sense of what I mean, you can try analysis using the UK National Forest Inventory: https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/bcd6742a2add4b68962aec073ab44138_0.zip?outSR=%7B%22wkid%22%3A27700%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A27700%7D

```
if (file.exists("data/National_Forest_Inventory_Woodland_Scotland_2017.shp") == FALSE) {
download.file("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/3cb1abc185a247a48b9d53e4c4a8be87_0.zip?outSR=%7B%22wkid%22%3A27700%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A27700%7D", 
              destfile = "data/National_Forest_Inventory_Woodland_Scotland_2017.zip")
unzip("data/National_Forest_Inventory_Woodland_Scotland_2017.zip", exdir = "data")
}
forestinv <- st_read("data/National_Forest_Inventory_Woodland_Scotland_2017.shp") %>% st_transform(paste0("+init=epsg:",27700))
```

You can see a concrete example in code [here](https://github.com/kidwellj/mapping_environmental_action/blob/master/mapping_draft-hpc_optimised_wilderness.Rmd) (especially lines 507-510)

Here's the key question-is it possible to parallelise these kinds of geospatial operations in R such as st_within? Even with a simplified set of geometries this process takes ages, but there aren't obvious ways to loop the operation and split across cores.

Comment: The way to go is to split the complex geometries. PostGIS has a function for that https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html but I do not know how to do that with R.

Comment: I like the sound of that and I guess I could preprocess data in postgis, but sure would be nice if I could keep it all in R

Comment: I was able to calculate point-in-polygon (random points in 1:50m country polygons) using a single-threaded process against a memory-based geometry table at a rate of [50 microseconds/query](https://community.esri.com/people/vangelo-esristaff/blog/2014/09/15/partitioning-large-geometries-to-improve-query-performance). Massive parallel techniques are probably not necessary to get adequate performance, provided you "dice your  Godzillas" (https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/analytics/dicing-godzillas-features-with-too-many-vertices/).

Comment: I would move your data to PostGIS or at least make sure you have a spatial index and that it is being used in the R code

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton - I'll do this and report back. seems like loading into PostGIS will also allow me to distribute the processing as user30184 suggest. IanTurton can you point me to some example of best practice or documentation re R code accessing a postGIS database in a way that utilises spatial index? I get what you're referring to, but haven't seen this in practice before.

Comment: Reverse your argument order and use `st_contains` instead of `st_within`. This allows internal indexes to be made on the polygons and should speed up your calculations by 10-20x. Some more details at https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1261 . Explicit subdivision, as used in PostGIS, should not be necessary or especially helpful in R, where all geometries are already in memory.